# Image upload to server using dart, flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

```
  upload(File imageFile) async {
     var uploadURL = "http://xxxxxx.org.xx/appdata/members/images";
     var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(imageFile.openRead()));
     var length = await imageFile.length();
     var uri = Uri.parse(uploadURL);
     var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
     var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length,
     filename: basename(imageFile.path));
     request.files.add(multipartFile);
     var response = await request.send();
     print(response.statusCode);
     response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
  print(value);
});}
```

But, it is throwing statuscode 301 and no file is uploaded to server's destination folder. what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The 301 HTTP code means that the server is trying to redirect you to another URL - see [wikipedia's list of response codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

I'd guess that your request has been redirected and the client isn't following... although MultipartRequest's `followRedirects` should be true by default you could try setting that explicitly, and you could increase `maxRedirects`.

I'd suggest testing out the API you're trying to use with curl (or similar) to make sure it's working as expected before trying with flutter.

Comment: My Friend, i tried with followRedirects and maxRedirects! but, it is the same issue.      request.followRedirects = true;
    request.maxRedirects = 10;